# 2 Object scope colliding with each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am doing insert and update with angular js but the problem is when i try to add user and change firstname then that change is reflected in my list of user first name and when i try to add new user then i have already my last record data in all those textbox.

**Code**:

User List:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td>
    <a href="#" ng-click="openPopUp(user)">
      <div class="edit-icon"></div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Add and Update Part:**

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" >
 <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" >
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.users = [];
    $scope.user = {};

 $scope.openPopUp = function (user) {
       $scope.user = user;
        ngDialog.open({
            templateUrl: 'templateId',
            scope: $scope
        });
    }

  $scope.save = function () { 
         $scope.users.push($scope.user);
            ngDialog.close();
}
```

Comment: The question isn't clear, and the `save` method is adding new user instead of editing the user in the popup

Comment: Pass a new scope to your dialog. Pass only the user maybe? So, scope: { user: user }.

Comment: @MuhammadAref save method will perform both add and edit.see i have updated question

Comment: @Learning. Please provide full working code. I have made a jsfiddle to help you. https://jsfiddle.net/r5urjg9v/9/

Answer (score 0):

Change your ng-model with an another name. It creates conflict with existing object.
Instead of user, write something like newUser.

Then in your save() function, you can replace previous object with the new one :

```
$scope.users.push($scope.newUser);
```